# how to show html fromjson in UI

Tags: android

im getting this json which contain css htmlwhich contain both images and text how i wil get and show on screen any idea? help me please im creating android app for website so what will i do????

```
 {"Status":1,
 "data":
[
 {"product_id":"8569",


 "image":"data\/osc\/0\/10011-Scalp-Med-Hsdf.jpg",
 "manufacturer_id":"0",

"name":"Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004..",

  "description":"<p><b><font face="Arial">Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004.. <\/font><\/b><\/p>    
  \r\n\r  
  \n<p><img border="0" height="257"
 src="http:\/\/www.megamall.com.pk\/image\/cache\/data\/10011-Scalp-Med-Hairfall-Solution- 
 800x800.jpg" width="261" \/><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
 Features: <\/font><\/b><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><font face="Arial" size="2"><b>Scalp Med Hair 
 Grow<\/b>    is an all natural formulation which includes the pure extracts of plants from 
3 different continents.<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nIs your Bald Spot getting bigger and bigger 
every   month?<br \/>\r\nIs the hair on your shower floor getting thicker while it gets
thinner and thinner on your head?<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nThen Scalp Med Hair Grow
is for you. Scalp Med Hair Grow is an all natural formulation which includes the
pure extracts of plants from 3 different continents. This tried and tested formulation
will reach deep down to cleanse, revitalize and unblock the hair follicles allowing vital   
nutrients to reach the hair roots and allow hair to grow again.<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nScalp
Med Hair Grow is the only ecological product of its kind capable of treating alopecia 
 efficiently. In the first month, continual use of Scalp Med Hair Grow will recover
  and strengthen the hair follicles. In the second month, your hair will stop 
 falling out altogether. And by the third month, new hair will start to grow.
 <\/font><\/p>\r\n",
  "meta_description":"Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004.. Rs. 1199.0000\/- Buy Scalp 
  Med Hair Grow PC-0004.. Lifestyle > Fragrances & Beauty in Pakistan","meta_keyword":
 "Tablet PC, Laptops, Mobile Phones, Watches, China Mobiles, Refurbished Mobiles, 
 Head Phones, Nokia Lumia, Nokia Asha, Samsung Galaxy, Computers, Home Appliances, 
Printer, Scanners, ipods, ipads, blackberry, htc, iphone, apple, nokia, sony, camera,    
samsun","product_h1":"",

 "image_path":"http:\/\/www.syyy.pk\/image\/data\/osc\/0\/10011-Scalp-Med-Hsdf.jpg"}

]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first have to parse the JSON and get the html parameter in the object

You can then use something like this to load it into a `WebView`

```
WebView webView = (WebView) notificationDialog.findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
webView.loadData("yourhtmlstring", "text/html", "utf8");
```

hope this helps

Comment: i did it like   String description = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");

Comment: i dont want to go on browser i want to show on application UI html test and images in description part

Comment: So you get it right to display the HTML but you cannot show images? Or don't you want to use a WebView at all?

Comment: see this url http://www.symbios.pk/lifestyle-in-pakistan/fragrances-beauty-in-pakistan/scalp-med-hair-grow-pc-0004--pakistan.html   description part i want to show like that with this html tag how i will show like that if i get string from json

Comment: There are two ways. Either you parse your html and get the data inside the respective tags and display them in native controls or you display it inside a WebView. Either way you will have to download that Image to display it. It won't display from the HTML in the JSON. You will have to ask the people from the website for a link to download the image from.

Comment: its not possible show complete html code which contain images show on screen without browser? i dont have acesss to website people im complately independant

Comment: u have any examples of this type problems??

Comment: Yes it is possible to show it without the browser. You get the data from the json, then you parse the HTML and then you display it. You won't be able to display the image because that image source isn't accessible. Either you display it without the image or you get it some other way. I can't help you further than I already have

Comment: i  found this http://javatechig.com/android/display-html-in-android-textview/ but is already hardcdoded define image name "hughjackman.jpg" in my case i dont know image name what will i do???